How to find and mark the lowest dip between two peaks in Pine Script?
I am trying to find and mark the lowest dip point between two peaks using the code below. However, I couldn't get it to work. The results are sometimes incorrect. I am trying to find peaks and dips using pivothigh in Pine Script. If the detected peak is higher than the previous peak, add a label to the lowest dip level between these two peaks
//@version=5
indicator("K Ksiw", overlay=true, calc_bars_count = 300)

kac_mum = input.int(2, 'Swing Length')

Tepe = ta.pivothigh(high, kac_mum, kac_mum)
Dip = ta.pivotlow(low, kac_mum, kac_mum)

color CLEAR = color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 100)

var int   Tepe_indexi      = na
var float Onceki_Tepe      = 0.000000
var int   Onceki_Tepe_indx = na
var bool  Tepe_Aktif       = na 
bool      Tepe_Varmi       = na 

var int     Dip_indexi      = na
var int     sonDip_indexi   = na

Dip_indexi :=  not na(Dip) ? bar_index - kac_mum : Dip_indexi
fiyatlar_array = array.new_float()


if not na(Tepe) and Tepe > Onceki_Tepe 
    
    Tepe_indexi      := bar_index - kac_mum      
    Tepe_Varmi       := true 
    Tepe_Aktif       := true
    if not na( Onceki_Tepe_indx ) and Dip_indexi > Onceki_Tepe_indx and Dip_indexi < Tepe_indexi
        
        sonDip_indexi := Dip_indexi - 2
        ff= low[Dip_indexi ]
        fiyatlar_array.push(ff)
        bulunan_F = array.min(fiyatlar_array)
        label.new(bar_index, ff, color = color.white, style = label.style_arrowup, yloc =yloc.belowbar)
        ///label.new(sonDip_indexi, low , color = color.white, style = label.style_arrowup, yloc =yloc.belowbar)


    Onceki_Tepe      := Tepe
    Onceki_Tepe_indx := bar_index - kac_mum

if Tepe_Varmi

    label.new(Tepe_indexi, Tepe,"HH", color=CLEAR, style=label.style_label_down, textcolor=color.yellow)

